# Why is Gnome Keyring or a program like it necessary? (NOT a question about how to get rid of it)

Tags: security

I read about what Gnome Keyring does and why it exists and lacking more detailed information I believe its a foolish concept. Why somebody thought that putting all your passwords into one place that gets unlocked when the user logs in is a good idea? And worse, it is in the home directory instead of buried somewhere only root can get at. That is so reckless that I must not understand something. Smart people program these systems so it must not be stupid but I would like to know why?  That info is not in the manual or the wiki.

Personally I don't want ANY passwords stored on a computer connected to the internet. I keep them on an encrypted USB and plug it in only during the brief time the password needs to be entered. Can someone enlighten me on what I am missing that makes the keyring a good thing? Other than convenience. For me, convenience is never a valid reason to reduce security.

Can someone help me understand? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why somebody thought that putting all your passwords into one place that gets unlocked when the user logs in is a good idea?

There's a good blog post on the UK's National Cyber Security Center titled [What does the NCSC think of password managers?](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/blog-post/what-does-ncsc-think-password-managers):

> Should I use a password manager?
>
> Yes. Password managers are a good thing.

You'll find that a lot of security advice now suggest using a password manager.

---

> That is so reckless that I must not understand something.

Simply: it's easier to hack the user than the system.  In the 50 odd years we've been using computer passwords, we've begun to understand much more of the behavioural science around them.

It would be much easier for me to get your password (here and now) by tricking you into handing it over, than for me to find where you live, steal your laptop, guess your encryption password.

That isn't to say that there's no risk in storing your passwords on an internet connected machine.  But those risks are a much  smaller area of attack than most average user's behaviour.  After all if someone wants your password that badly [they can always get it](https://xkcd.com/538/).

Password managers are there to fix **massive** problems in user's behaviour at the expense of a **tiny** added technical risk.

---

Password managers tackle two really troublesome aspects of passwords:

- People [reuse passwords](https://xkcd.com/792/) between different things.
- People are bad at generating passwords

Password managers make it trivial to use unique passwords for every app.  They also make the user care much less if the password is memorable.  This makes it much more likely the user will have a [high entropy password](https://xkcd.com/936/).

---

> Personally I don't want ANY passwords stored on a computer connected to the internet. I keep them on an encrypted USB and plug it in only during the brief time the password needs to be entered.

That's great.  If that's what you genuinely do with all your passwords and you never take shortcuts in sharing the same password between services just because you can remember it then this works for you.

The problem is that people are very prone to cut corners when they find a task repetitive, boring or generally obstructive.

So doing something like you describe might work perfectly for you but, if you were the IT admin of a large network, it would be a bad idea to expect staff members to do this.  Too many would cut corners because most of them couldn't be bothered to find their USB key, decrypt it, copy-paste from the right file and unplug it again every time they needed a password.

> For me, convenience is never a valid reason to reduce security.

Convenience security feature.

Comment: Thank you Phillip.  That's what I wanted to know.  There is no technical reason related to the operating system function that requires it so I can remove it.  I get what you are saying. I remember all the idiots I had to work with before I retired and your point is quite correct.  I just wish that the programmers would at least make it possible for a security-conscious person to remove or disable the "feature" easily.

Comment: I use a password manager but the database is on a USB drive.  Consequently I have no idea what my passwords are and I use the maximum the site will allow. So my Amazon account is 64 characters.  I liked the cartoon!

Answer (score 2):

> For me, convenience is never a valid reason to reduce security.

I have news for you: for the vast majority of people, security at the cost of convenience comes at the cost of security. People put their passwords on paper notes in their desk. They store them on notes shown on their desktop without any encryption. They couldn't care less about what people like you and me think of their security practices.

And that coupled with keyring programs handling other secrets (such as GPG keys, SSH keys, certificates, etc.) makes a keyring a hell of a good thing for convenient security. The main problem with the setup is the additional layer of convenience added by this:

> one place that gets unlocked when the user logs in

That's how it's set up by default in many distros since otherwise you wouldn't even get people to use it. It doesn't have to be. The keyring password can be separate from your login password, in which case it will not be unlocked on login. This is actually a problem for people who had to change their passwords from the CLI instead of the GUI, since the GUI changes the keyring password too, but the CLI doesn't, so now people are prompted to unlock their keyrings on login, which annoys them and now they just nuke the keyring altogether. And boom, now Chrome on Linux is storing their passwords in plaintext (or at least, it used to if a keyring wasn't present). That is a considerably worse situation than having them stored encrypted in the keyring was.

> And worse, it is in the home directory instead of buried somewhere only root can get at.

I honestly don't know what root has to do with this. Root shouldn't have any idea what the user's password is, so it shouldn't be able to use the encrypted data even if it could get at it; and the average user shouldn't need to have root for getting their own data.

Comment: Thank you Muru that was also very helpful.  Yea I would rather not use the internet then to use Chrome.  I use Tor through a VPN.   I spent years in the government doing work where security was paramount so old habits are hard to break, plus it taught me to  have little confidence that encryption can provide protection by itself.   I meant that if root access were required the passwords would be safer than in my Home if someone were to gain access to my computer while I am logged in.